# Does a larger lens filter size imply more light and better photos?

Tags: lens, filter-diameter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the lens diameter influence photo quality?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2890/how-does-the-lens-diameter-influence-photo-quality)

I'm wondering about 50mm f/1.4 for Nikons. The Nikon 50mm f/1.4D has a 52mm filter size. The Sigma 50mm f/1.4 has a 77mm filter size. There's a lot more glass in the Sigma.

So, does having a larger filter size mean that a lens will collect more light, and therefore produce better photographs?